# Failed to compile values file. Android studio

Tags: android, xml, android-studio

Hello i keep getting errors saying that the value was previously deffined and i dont know how to fix it any help is much appreciated
[image: Here is a photo of some of the errors]

Comment: You have the same resource defined in two places.  Get rid of one of them.

Comment: But if i delete it from attr wouldnt it break it even more?

Comment: This probably means you have the same library included twice. Maybe two different versions of a library are included in different modules.